# How to create Global DataFrame and append the same in outside the Function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to create Global DataFrame and append the same in outside the Function in Python

How can i create Global Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from numpy import *

l=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Article name','Ean','Status'])

def d():
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Article name":['shirt'],"Ean":[89],             "Status":'Success'})


d()
l=l.append(df2)

print(l)


print(l)
```

```
Article name Ean Status
Shirt         89  Success
```

Comment: Please format code properly when asking a question

Answer (score 0):

Python variables have normally function scope, so here `df2` is declared in a function, and is destroyed at the end of the function call. The Pythonic way would be to return it:

```
...
def d():
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Article name":['shirt'],"Ean":[89],             "Status":'Success'})
    return df2


l=l.append(d())
...
```

If you really want to use a global variable you must explicitely declare it inside the function:

```
...
def d():
    global df2
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Article name":['shirt'],"Ean":[89],             "Status":'Success'})


d()
l=l.append(df2)
...
```